# How can I change where pytorch looks for my Cuda installation?

Tags: python, installation, pytorch

I'm trying to run stable diffusion locally using Windows 10 but I'm having trouble with my cuda and pytorch installations. I've tested the Cuda install (adding some vectors) and it works, yet pytorch claims it's not available.

Can I reset pytorch? How can I change where python or pytorch is looking for Cuda?

I am able to see that Cuda is installed using 'nvcc --version'

```
C:\Users\Nolasaurus\OneDrive\Python\stable-diffusion>nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_May__3_19:00:59_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0
```

but pytorch returns not available.

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

I have uninstalled and re-installed pytorch with no change.

Comment: How did you install pytorch (pip/conda command)? did you falsely install the cpu only version?

Comment: I followed this guide  https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#windows-python and ran this command:

'conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia'

Comment: Can you verify the correct CUDA version of the torch build with `torch.version.cuda`

Comment: That doesn't return anything:

'import torch'
'torch.version.cuda'

Comment: If it returns `None` that likely means that it somehow installed the CPU version despite you using the correct command.  Have you tried using `pip` instead of `conda`? (`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117`)

Comment: I looked through my packages and found that pytorch was version 1.12.1 instead of 1.13.1. I must have made a mistake while installing it before. Now `torch.version.cuda` returns '11.7' and `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `True`